# Passing access tokens to subsequent API Calls

Tags: javascript, api, express, cookies, access-token

I'm using simple-oatuh2 and I'm currently able to generate all my tokens through my redirect URI. I'm having a little trouble figuring out how to pass these tokens into a redirect after the user grants user data to the app. Once the tokens are generated, I thought I could store them in my cookies and then redirect the user:

```
app.get('/authorize', (req, res) => {
  const { code } = req.query;
  const options = {
    code
  };
  oauth2.authorizationCode.getToken(options, (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error('Access Token Error', error.message);
      return res.json('Authentication failed');
    }

    console.log('The resulting token: ', result);
    const token = oauth2.accessToken.create(result);

    const cookies = [
      `token=${result.access_token};Max-Age=4000`,
      `refresh-token=${result.refresh_token};Max-Age=4000`,
      `token-expires=${result.expires_at.getTime()};Max-Age=4000`,
      `email=${result.email ? result.email : ''}';Max-Age=4000`
    ];
    res.set('Set-Cookie', cookies);
    // return res.status(200).json(result);
    console.log(req.header);
    res.redirect(302, '/me');
  });
});
```

on the `/me` endpoint, i'm consoling my headers but there are no cookies being stored and therefore the access tokens are not accessible. How can I pass them? Do I need to start a session?

This is the [API](https://goto-developer.logmeininc.com/gotomeeting-api-overview) I'm working with.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you used document.cookie?

Comment: Have you looked at the **[Response.cookie](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.cookie)** method?

Comment: @NegiRox: this is on the server.